# IGraphM on Apple Silicon?

Tags: mac-os-x, compatibility, igraphm, apple-silicon

I recently got a new laptop with Apple's M1 Max processor and now the IGraphM installer

```
Get["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/master/IGInstaller.m"]
```

returns

[image]

FYI, I ran this in *Mathematica* version 13.0.1 on macos 12.3.1.

So what I'd like to ask:

1. Is it possible to install IGraphM on the M1 architecture? (Given the fact that it runs on ARM-based machines like RaspberryPi, the answer is probably "yes".)
2. How to install it and make it run?

Comment: I don't currently have the time to check this, but hopefully a useful suggestion. There's [`Rosetta`](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861). "Rosetta 2 enables a Mac with Apple silicon to use apps built for a Mac with an Intel processor."

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Recently, I also purchased (not delivered yet) Mac Studio Max M1 and contacted MMA Support about its compatibility with MMA version 11.3 (my version). They informed me that I need to upgrade my version to a higher version due to changes in macOS.

Comment: It looks like IGraphM specifically lists which systems it is compatible with [here](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/master/IGraphM/PacletInfo.m#L15), this is why the paclet issues a message and won't load.  As an experiment, could you open the paclet info file (found in the directory `PacletObject["IGraphM"]["Location"]`) and manually add your `$SystemID` to that list?  I would expect it to *just work* via rosetta but I am far from an expert

Comment: I'm very sorry about this, I simply didn't have time to fix everything I needed and create a new binary (which is also a bit troublesome since I need ask for access to a suitable computer...)

Comment: @Szabolcs No reason to feel sorry! Maybe we can work out something together? E.g., I could bould the binaries if you tell me how to do it. I am going to write you an email.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks, I've just tried that... to no avail. There is a dynamic library missing. And just planting the analogous Intel binaries there does not work. Maybe Szabolcs can tell me to build the project so that we can upload the MacOSX-ARM64 binaries...

Comment: @TugrulTemel I am already using the ARM64 version of _Mathematica_. The problem is that some parts of the (external) IGraphM package have to be recompiled, too.

Comment: @Szabolcs and hopefully Henrik will also see this comment. Wouldn't Docker be less troublesome for this purpose? Essentially, having `IGraphM` on Docker, with the AMD-64 architecture, and from the terminal on the Apple silicon using a specific option in the `docker run [docker_image]` command to make it ARM-64. That's how I mean it. Not sure, if it can work on this specific example, but I did something similar recently. I refrain from writing an answer on that, as I am not sure if it will be helpful, but if you want I can post something once I get back home

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Did you solve your problem? I would be much interested in the solution.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Thanks for asking. Well, not yet solved. Szabolcs told me that he is going to add support for Apple Silicon soon. Alas, he is quite busy at the moment. We will certainly let you know when we have solved the issue. =)

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Thanks for the info. I look forward to hearing from you when the issue is solved.

Comment: @TugrulTemel Please check the answer I posted.

Comment: @JasonB. Please check the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Release 0.6 with Apple Silicon support is out now.

(Version 0.5.x does not support Apple Silicon, but you can run the Intel version of Mathematica even on ARM Macs.)

Comment: Thank for this. I will try it with my new Mac Studio M1 Max and let you know the result.